# cudaMalloc runtime error

Tags: c, cuda

I have a  problem executing the following code on the host and am not sure where I am going wrong. my understanding is that I need to allocate enough memory to store the contents of textData which is textLength in size on the device, I malloc with sizeof(char) * textLength which should give me enough space, then I use cudaMemcpy to copy all of the values from textData to the allocated space on the device. my exception reads "Access violation reading location 0x000000000501f80400" which is the memory address of my cuTextArray on the device.

```
texture<char, cudaTextureType1D, cudaReadModeElementType> textDataRef;

        int textLength = 10000000
        cudaArray *cuTextArray;
        checkCudaErrors (cudaMalloc(&cuTextArray, sizeof(char)*textLength));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(cuTextArray, textData, sizeof(char)*textLength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(textDataRef, cuTextArray, textDataRef.channelDesc));
```

I cannot use cudaMallocArray as my data is too big for the buffer - maximum of 8192 bytes

Exception here where it seems to crash at binding texture to array snippet of code inside cuda_runtime.h:

[image]

Comment: which of the 3 operations (`cudaMalloc`, `cudaMemcpy`, `cudaBindTextureToArray`) actually fails with the exception? please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The behavior is really not helpful, I set a breakpoint at the cudaMalloc call, on running the program the breakpoint shifts down to the cudaMemcpy call. Pressing f10 once takes me to cuda_runtime.h to cudaMemcpyToSymbolAsync where pressing f10 again results in the exception

Comment: Please provide a link to the resource which says the limit to work with `cudaArray` is 8kB. And if it concerns the `cudaMemcpyToArray` as well, then you should clearly state it. Also, if the limit really _is_ 8kB and you want to allocate more, then you may be misusing the `cudaArray` ...

Comment: Link to resource where theres a limit, forum post. My intention is simply to use texture memory to hold my textData, I'm not doing anything that I would consider difficult or strange. I simply don't understand what I am doing wrong https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/370124/cudamallocarray-bug-cuda-error-invalid-argument/

Comment: Linked resource is 8 years old and is talking about then current relase, which definitely is not the _current_ release. Did you actually tried to use `cudaMallocArray` and `cudaMemcpyToArray` ? If yes, then what was the outcome?

Comment: I used cudaMallocArray and cudaMemcpyToArray for a small data of 25 characters, it worked fine, when using it on my actual data of 10000000, I encounter a runtime error "runtime API error 11: invalid argument"

Comment: You do realise that the 8192 number you are fixating on is the texture *width* and not the size in bytes? The compute 1.x hardware of the era had  limit of 8192 wide textures bound to CUDA arrays. That has been raised to 65536 in CC >=2 hardware. If you use linear memory, the *width* limit is 2^27 . Unless you are using a very old GPU, a size of 10000000 should work. But without an actual repro case, who knows what your real problem is

Comment: To take a step back away from any misgivings or misunderstandings I have. What is the most simple recommended way to store 1000000 characters into texture memory. my understanding is that if I have a texture reference where the data type is char, where I want it to be held in a 1d texture array, the width of the texture is needed to be textLength, how is it possible to do this when the max width of the texture is 8192 and I have 1000000 characters i need to store in texture memory

Comment: Again, because this limits are *widths* and because 32 bit types are supported, you can pack you data in `char4`  and use arrays with a maximum of 65536*4, or 134217728 * 4 with linear memory. If those limits are too small for you, then you need a new approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate the responses. I have one last question regarding a different approach, is it possible to bind my texture reference to a simple char pointer in global memory, my understanding is that texture memory exists in global memory exactly the same as a regular variable on the device, but you use a special syntax like tex1Dfetch to look up elements from that pointer. Am I correct in that this will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out I can stay away from the entire array nonsense by using a standard char pointer with a reference and a different binding call to get it working. Extremely simple stuff, bit odd it wasn't easily answerable.

```
//Allocate Memory
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc(&d_textData, sizeof(char) * textLength) ); 
//Copy Host To Device
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(d_textData, textData, sizeof(char)* textLength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
//Bind reference to block of memory
    checkCudaErrors ( cudaBindTexture(NULL,&texTextRef,d_textData,&texTextRef.channelDesc, sizeof(char) * textLength ) );
```

lookup values using

```
tex1Dfetch(texTextRef,k+index)
```